# Unable to perform jQuery function because table was loaded after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

My searches has proved futile and I am hoping someone can give me some assistance. I am fairly new to javascripting as well.

I have built a site that consists of several DIV tags with an iFRAME in between.
I have setup a Javascript which loads a table inside the iframe's HTML page.
The first cell of each row consists of a name.

I want to be able to click on each row and have the name in the first cell returned. For now I have been using alert function to determine if my code is working.

Here is my iframe source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./cgi-bin/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpGetVMList(strURL) {
   var xmlHttpReqVMList = false;
   var self = this;
   // Mozilla/Safari/Chrome
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    self.xmlHttpReqVMList = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   //IE
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    self.xmlHttpReqVMList = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   self.xmlHttpReqVMList.open('GET', strURL, true);
   self.xmlHttpReqVMList.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
   self.xmlHttpReqVMList.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (self.xmlHttpReqVMList.readyState == 4) {
       updatepage(self.xmlHttpReqVMList.responseText);
    }
   }
   self.xmlHttpReqVMList.send(null);
}

function updatepage(str) {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}

$("#result").ready(function() {
JavaScript:xmlhttpGetVMList("./cgi-bin/db_list_vm.cgi");

//alert('Script DIV loaded');  // <-- useful to confirm the event has completed.
});

$("#result").ready(function () {
var table = document.getElementById('VMList'),
    cells = table.getElementByTagName('td');

for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
   cells[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.innerText);
    }
}
});


</script>

<html>
<head>
<link href="./styles/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="countleft"></div>
<div id="countright"> <b>VM Count: </b></div>
<br>
<br>
<form name="f1">
<div id="result">Loading ......<img src="./images/loading.gif" alt="loading"></img></div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

The above code runs and fills in the innerText of DIV ID result with the following:

```
<table id="VMList">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="vmname">VMName</th>
<th class="ipaddr">IP Address</th>
<th class="FQDN">FQDN</th>
<th class="Team">Team Name</th>
<th class="Owner">Owner</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr id="vmname">
<td class="vmname">SomeName</td>
<td class="ipaddr">PlaceHolder</td>
<td class="FQDN">PlaceHolder</td>
<td class="Team">PlaceHolder</td>
<td class="Owner">PlaceHolder</td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>
```

My script section that makes each row clickable doesn't seem to work.
I believe it is because the code is running before the Javascript finishes creating the table.

I'm looking for help getting this code to work after the table is created:

```
$("#result").ready(function () {
var table = document.getElementById('VMList'),
    cells = table.getElementByTagName('td');

for (var i=0,len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
   cells[i].onclick = function() {
    alert(this.innerText);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: .ready() doesn't work that way. There is only one DOMContentLoaded event, and it only happens once.

Comment: `$('#result').on('click', '#VMList td', function() { alert($(this).text()); });`

Comment: You just need to run the code in the `onreadystatechange` method for your AJAX, like with the `updatepage` call.

Comment: @adeneo there you go again! Beast! haha

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I can get adeneo's suggestion to work. No errors just no option to click the first cell of each row on my table.

Comment: @ian - I've been thinking about the onreadystatechange but I can't figure out how to code that. I can get multiple scripts to run when the site is loaded but I can't figure out how run a script after the div is updated.

Comment: How about doing yourself a favor and use $.ajax. You're loading jQuery anyway and one of the main benefits of jQuery is easy ajax functionality, but you've opted to do something that's ten times harder for no apparent reason whatsoever? The delegated click function above should work pretty much the same way as the (again ten times as complicated) native JS function you're using, but if it is'nt firing on the first cell, you'll have to figure out another selector that works.

Comment: @adeno - I have to say that jQuery.ajax (or .get and .post) are freaking awesome!! I'm a total newb at this and when i first searched for implementing ajax and followed some examples I assumed what I wrote was using the jquery. Now I know different. you comment now works. Only problem is that I'd like to try to get each cell in the row to print only the data from the first cell. With your command each cell displays the text of itself. I assume that I will need to use some sort of indexing but I am not sure where to begin. Do you have any reference material that might help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using $(document).ready instead? Also, us an Ajax call (or trigger) using on-click.